# Add hash to current location when scrolling into the view

Tags: angular

I have a situation where I have to use a `@HostListener` to navigate to element within my page:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    let fragment = document.getElementById(href.replace('#', ''));
    if (fragment != undefined) { 
        fragment.scrollIntoView(); 
        // want to update current location by adding a `#{fragment}` to it
     }
  }
```

The scrolling works but I have a problem that location does not get updated accordingly, I wonder how would you do that when scrolling into the view/section?

Also I want to be able to scroll right where the view starts, however if you click on Url 1 or Url 2 you will see that header is hiding the top part of the view/section (see stackbliz link below)

I have a feeling that I have to use [pushState](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation#pushState) in combination with [replaceState](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation#replacestate) but haven't figure out that yet

UPDATE:
My html is dynamic that comes from the server, so I can not use directives within that html

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxvsts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-html.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Findex.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should update the route using the router :

```
const fragment = e.target.getAttribute('href')?.slice(1);
this.router.navigate(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url, {
  fragment,
});
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jwn99h?file=src%2Fapp%2Flinkify.directive.ts)

Comment: my html is dynamic that comes from the server, directives won't work

Comment: @sreginogemoh Then just using `router.navigate` to your fragment should be fine.

Comment: if I use just that `this.router.navigate([href]);` I've got an error ` NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%23url3'` however the fragment doesn't gets added to the location address  bar using this method either

Comment: The fragment should be in the fragment part, don't pass the whole url.  Also how do you get dynamic html in your angular app ?

Comment: here is the stackbliz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxvsts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-html.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Flinkify.directive.ts,src%2Findex.html

Comment: @sreginogemoh see my update. router.navigate need your current router + a separated fragment.

Comment: if I am using this code getting an error `ERROR TypeError: p is undefined`

Comment: would you mind to alter the stackbliz example?

Comment: My bad, it could be working. See my update @sreginogemoh

Comment: seems does not work, also I believe that using `router.navigate` won't give you any control over the content section offset, using `scrollIntoView` I can do `fragment.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });`

Comment: @sreginogemoh The stackblitz works fine, open the console for a scrollbar to appear.

Comment: Yeah i c, it is working but using router.navigate has this limitations that I noted in previous comments